# Google API IP range for firewall whitelisting

Tags: google-api, ip, whitelist

We are trying to whitelist googleapis.com for oauth implementation. Is there any way to acquire the range IP addresses used by Google? URL whitelisting doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you get some solution about?

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322?hl=en

Google publishes:

- The [complete list](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json) of IP ranges that it announces to the internet.
- A [list](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json) of Google Cloud customer-usable global and regional external IP address ranges.

The default domains' IP address ranges for Google APIs and services fit within the list of ranges between these 2 sources. (Subtract the usable ranges from the complete list.)